# Checking if an optional paramater is specified in a function inside another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which has an optional parameter. Call this function func1 with optional argument `a` which is initially set to `None`

I want to use this function as an argument to another function call it func2.

Hence, I want a function like:

```
def func2(func1):
     If a is not None:
          .......
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: But do you want to know if `a` was set to default `None` when defining the function? Or do you want to know whether after calling `func1`, `a` was passed or not (i.e: what value had `a` when `func1` was called) ?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if a value was passed to the optional paramater ```a``` when ```func1``` was called

Comment: So you're passing the function object or the value returned by `func1` to `func2`?

Comment: The function object

Comment: Well, I only can figure out one way of doing that... Let me elaborate the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "when `func1` was called"?  It's not being called anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: `func1` *wasn't* called; you just got a reference to it. Whether you call `func1("foo")` or `func1()` inside `func2` is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `func1`'s handler as an argument (which doesn't have arguments with parenthesis), you can't do this and need to define `a` as an argument for `func2`. Like this:

```
def func2(func1, a=None):
   ...
```

If you are using `func1`'s return value, the argument's to `func1` are lost when `func2` is invoked and again the only solution I can think of is to define `a` as an argument for `func2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check what parameter is passed to func1 using this -

```
def func2(func1):
     If a is not None:
          .......
```

In this, You are just passing the `func1` to `func2` as parameter. Nowhere has it been explicitly specified what parameter `func1` will be using. So, You will have to decide what you are going to pass to `func1` inside your `func2` code.

---

Maybe you are looking for something like this -

```
def func2(func1,a=None):
     if a != None:       # When a non - None parameter is passed
          func1(a)
     else :
          # Something when a is none
```

Here, you can check what parameter is going to be passed to `func1` since during the call to `func2`, you will have to specify either 1 or 2 arguments. a is set to None by default. If a 2nd parameter is not passed to `func2`, it means that no parameter for `func1` has been given. This means `func1` was meant to be called without a parameter ( or using the default set parameter value ).

---

Or maybe you are looking to do something like this -

```
def func1(a=None):
    func1.a = a
    print(a)
    
def func2(f):
     f(2)         # Called with a paramter, so f.a will not be None
     print(f.a)
     f()          # Called without a param, so f.a will be None
     print(f.a)

func2(func1)
```

**Output :**

```
2
2
None
None
```

Here, the function object will set the parameter passed to it as its object and then once it called, depending on what the value of `func1.a` is, you can get what was the value with which the function was called last time. You can modify the above snippet for what you asked in question as -

```
def func1(a=None):
    func1.a = a
    
def func2(f):
     if f.a is not None:
         print("Last call with paramter - " + str(f.a))
     else :
         print("Last Function call was made without a paramter")

func1()
func2(func1) 

func1(2)
func2(func1)
```

**Output :**

```
Last Function call was made without a paramter
Last call with paramter - 2
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but to achieve what you desire, you can take advantage of the fact that functions (since they are objects) can be assigned with attributes.

```
def func(a=None):
    func.a = a
    print(a)

def func_2(f):
    if f.a is not None:
        print(f.a)
```

Note that in order for this to work as you want, you would need to make sure that `func` was called before `func_2`

```
>>> func(1)
1
>>> func_2(func)
1
```